# Why can't we ping the gateway on our Open-vSwitch network configuration on Proxmox 6.1-3?

Tags: proxmox, lacp, openvswitch

We are trying to get open vswitch working on 10 hosts running Proxmox 6.1-3.  We think we have a configuration that should work, but it doesn't and we can't ping the gateway.  These are hosts with 4 nics, we want to bond them with LACP then establish a bridge where we can have virtual NICs on different VLANs.  We don't have much experience with ProxMox (I've used single-hosts at home, this is an experiment in our lab) and we have no experience with open-vswitch.

We're using this page, and Example 2 is the template for what we're doing: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Open_vSwitch

For our test, even though we're going for LACP, we have 3/4 ports disabled on the switch to simplify troubleshooting.  With the below configuration, we cannot ping the gateway.  I believe we have a problem with the ovs config, specifically the fact that the interface for port vmbr0 is being listed as vmbr0 itself and not bond0, but we don't see how to correct that.  There are no errors showing in systemctl status networking or systemctl status ovs-*. Below is the configuration for /etc/network/interfaces (please excuse any typos; I re-typed this from a photo of the console):

```
# Loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-vmbr0 bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    ovs_bridge vmbr0
    ovs_type OVSBond
    ovs_bonds eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
    ovs_options bond-mode=balance-tcp lacp=active other_config:lacp-time=fast
    ovs_mtu 9000

allow-ovs vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
    ovs_type OVSBridge
    ovs_ports bond0 vlan10
    ovs_mtu 9000

allow-vmbr vlan10
iface vlan10 inet static
    ovs_type OVSIntPort
    ovs_bridge vmbr0
    ovs_options tag=10
    ovs_extra set interface ${IFACE} external-ids:iface-id=$(hostname -s)-${IFACE}-vif
    address 10.1.10.75
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.1.10.253
    ovs_mtu 9000
```

Following this, we get the following when we do "ip a"

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:f5:7e:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::1a03:73ff:fef5:7ea5/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:f5:7e:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:f5:7e:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master ovs-system state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:f5:7e:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e2:ba:2b:06:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:9a:fb:4a:4f:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:f5:7e:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::1a03:73ff:fef5:7ea5/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vlan10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:1d:a2:b8:63:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.10.75/24 scope global vlan10
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::741d:a2ff:feb8:6309/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:05:b7:42:a3:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::2005:b7ff:fe42:a318/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I run "ovs-vsctl show" we see this:

```
f1733867-7e12-4d9a-bcf2-364bf38cd161
    Bridge "vmbr0"
        Port "bond0"
            Interface "eno2"
            Interface "eno3"
            Interface "eno4"
            Interface "eno1"
        Port "vmbr0"
            Interface "vmbr0"
                type: internal
        Port "vlan10"
            tag: 10
            Interface "vlan10"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.10.1"
```

Any help or insight is appreciated!